# Is Opera's SpeedDial view still manageable?

Tags: icons, opera

According to [this link](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-speed-dial-enhancements/), all the Opera specific icons, CSS sections and server-side headers are no longer supported in Opera newer than 12.16.

However in Opera 16.0, if you add sites like YouTube or Facebook, even [Allegro.pl](http://www.allegro.pl) you don't get a miniature of the website but a fancy label instead.

Is it still possible to manage this view in current Opera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the partner sites come with images included with Opera. They can not be customized.

Comment: I've lost a day on this. With the help of my team at TurboLab.it and some HTTP examination, I can confirm what @PetterNilsen said: Amazon, Facebook and the like all have internal logo associations. No way for us mortal to do the same, for now.